# How to set the different QLineEdit Text in a TableView

Tags: qt, qtableview, qt4.7, model-view, qlineedit

I have 3 `QLineEdits` (say Name, Address & Phone No.), a `QPushButton` (Add button) and a `QTableView`.

When I have entered text in all the `QLineEdits`, and if I click the Add button, all 3 texts of the `QLineEdits` should be added in the first row of the `QTableView`.

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't understand if you want to attache your 3 `QLineEdit`'s to a row on `QTableView`, or you want to add the content of `QLineEdit`'s to the first row of `QTableView`.

Comment: I want to add only the contents of the 3 QLineEdit to the first row of the QTableView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel();
model->setRowCount(3);

yourTableView->setModel(model);

connect(yourBtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(addData()));
...

void YourClass::addData()
{
    QStandardItem *nameItem = new QStandardItem(nameEdit->text());
    QStandardItem *addressItem = new QStandardItem(addressEdit->text());
    QStandardItem *phoneItem = new QStandardItem(phoneEdit->text());

    QList<QStandardItem*> row;
    row << nameItem << addressItem << phoneItem;

    model->appendRow(row);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it Works fine. But the Thing is if suppose am adding another **QPushButton** (eg. MODIFY). Now **if i click on any particular row of the QTableView the items in the row** should again be placed in their **QLineEdit's**. this is just for modifying the row again **without double clicking on each cell of the QTableView**. How can do this. kindly help.